# Add data labels to ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I try to add data labels to ggplot legend but don't know how to do it. Could you please help me?
Here is the code and two plots: the ggplot one is the one I want to improve and second just shows all the details I try to present.
All the annotate_custom part seems to be ignored

[image: Link to my plots]

[image]

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x = obs, y = predicted, group = Model)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = Model), alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = wes_palette(n = 5, name = "FantasticFox1")) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-0.5, 0.5), ylim = c(-0.5, 0.5)) +
  annotate_custom("text",label = c("RMSE", paste("LM = ",round(rmse_data[j,1],digits=2)),
   paste("GBM = ",round(rmse_data[j,5],digits=2))))
```

Edit:

I finally got there:

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x = obs, y = predicted, group = Model)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = Model), alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = wes_palette(n = 5, name = "FantasticFox1")) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-0.4, 0.5), ylim = c(-0.4, 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  annotate("text", x = 0.35:0.5, y = 0.48, label = paste("SD(price) = ",round(rmse_data[j,5],digits=4)), 
           size = 3.5) +
  annotate("text", x = 0.35:0.5, y = 0.43, label =paste("LM = ",round(rmse_data[j,1],digits=4)), 
           size = 3.5, colour = "#DD8D29") +
  annotate("text", x = 0.35:0.5, y = 0.38, label =paste("CART = ",round(rmse_data[j,2],digits=4)), 
           size = 3.5, colour = "#E2D200") +
  annotate("text", x = 0.35:0.5, y = 0.33, label =paste("RF =  ",round(rmse_data[j,3],digits=4)), 
           size = 3.5, colour = "#46ACC8") +
  annotate("text", x = 0.35:0.5, y = 0.28, label =paste("GBM =  ",round(rmse_data[j,4],digits=4)), 
           size = 3.5, colour = "#E58601")
```

[image: Link to my plots]

Comment: Did you try different ```x``` and ```y```values in the ```annotate_custom```-call? It seems that  ```4``` and ```5``` are simply out of bounds of your chart. BTW it is easier to answer your question if you follow [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried. It actually ignores all this part. I get the same plot when I write only the four first lines. Also thanks for the link. I edited the question